# Bypass Jwplayer from hyper cache

Tags: caching, wordpress, jwplayer

I need to bypass from **Hyper Cache** plugin the content of **jwplayer** that regenerates every 2 hours.
Jwplayer is inside div on every single post, but when video url **expire** (and regenerate with a new url) users see: *no playable source found*.

example:

```
<div id="jwplayer_1234">loading the player...</div>
<script>jwplayer code with video urls that changes every 2 hours</script>
```

There is a solution to **bypass** certain piece of code? Please help me!!!
I'm going crazy, I can not find a solution!!!

Comment: Sorry, is HypeCache some sort of WP plugin? Does it actually regenerate the files names?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyper-cache/  this is the plugin :) Hi ethan! I want to know if there is a way like this: onlclick reload jwplayer, or something other method to have fresh content inside jwplayer script tag

Comment: You could always do a JS onlick and either call jwplayer().load() to load a new file again, or just call a new jwplayer().setup entirely.

Comment: mmm... ok, how to call a new setup?

Comment: Oh, wait, that is hard to do since you are using the WP plugin. I suggest using jwplayer().load('something.mp4') then instead.